# How to set an env variable during build that is coming from package.json

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

What do I need to add to nuxt.conf.js to get the version from package.json and store the value in an environment variable?

I want to set the version of package.json in a vuex store like:

```
state: {
  version: process.env.version
}
```

I tried putting this in nuxt.conf.js but that didn't work.

```
 env: {
   version: JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version)
 }
```

I know how to do this with Quasar as in quasar.conf.js

```
build: {
  env: {VERSION: JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version)}
}
```

So how do achieve the same effect with nuxt?

Answer (score 2):

```
env: {
 version: JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version)
}
```

This actually works but only when you restart a build.
I was expecting it to work dynamically but it didn't.
It's not really a problem, it's only needed when you do a production build.

In my package.json I have a build script like this:

```
"build": "nmp version patch && nuxt build"
```

This will increase the version number that I display in my nuxt app.
I always forgot to do this manually so I automated this.